# put spans and divs around paginate_links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I wanna style my links and in order to do that I need some spans and divs around it but I dunno how it's done when using paginate_links() from WordPress.
Can you help me to do that?

```
    <div class="pagination">
    <?php echo  
        $pagination = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
            'format'    => '',
            'prev_text' => __('&#8592; Previous'),
            'next_text' => __('Next &#8594;'),
            'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
            'current' => $page,
            'type' => 'plain'
            )); 
            ?>
        </div>
```

so far it looks like that

[image]

Comment: What is the generated HTML?

Comment: There's none. How it looks now does the paginate_links function

Comment: Try to inspect the generated HTML content in your browser's dev tools and see what elements with what classes it generates. Then you can target these elements in your CSS and style them.

Comment: Put what you want to execute the project and the generated HTML pagination. You can probably do it with css alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change li to div / span whatever. The main difference is to change your "type" from "plain" to "array" and then you can do what you want with it.

```
<?php
    
         global $wp_query;
    
         $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    
          $prev_next =  paginate_links( array(
                  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                   'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                   'type'         => 'array',
                   'prev_text'    => __('&#8592; Previous'),
                   'next_text'    => __('Next &#8594;')
                    ) );
    
            if($prev_next){ ?>
                <ul>
    
                    <?php
                       foreach($prev_next as $key=>$val){
    
    
                        if (strpos($val,"'page-numbers current'") !== false) {
                         echo '<li class="active item">'.$val.'</li>';
                        } elseif (strpos($val,'"next page-numbers"') !== false || strpos($val,'"prev page-numbers"') !== false  ) {
    
                         echo'<li>'.$val.'</li>';
                        } else {
    
                             echo '<li class="item">'.$val.'</li>';
                        }
    
                    } ?>
              </ul>
<?php } ?>
```